# How to stop tracking the content of a directory in git?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory named `img`. I want to that directory be exits on the repo, but always it should be empty. I mean just the content of that directory should be untracked.

Here is a simplified of my project:

```
myproject/
    .git/
    application/
    public/
        img/
            img1.jpg
            img2.jpg
    vendor/
    composer.json
    composer.lock
```

I want to make it like this on repository:

```
myproject/
    .git/
    application/
    public/
        img/
    vendor/
    composer.json
    composer.lock
```

How can I do that?

---

According to some researches, I have to use `.gitignore` file. But how? Should I make a `.gitignore` file on the root of project and write this in it?

```
// .gitignore file
public/img/*
```

Or should I make a `.gitignore` inside `img` directory? If yes should I write what thing in it?

---

Ok, now I got a new problem. Let's explain what I want to do exactly. **Here is the scenario:**

I develop my website locally and push it on the github repository. Then I go in the server and do a `git pull`. Also there is an `img` directory that contains all user's avatars. All I'm trying to do is to keep the real-users avatar on `img` directory. If I put the whole `img` directory inside `.gitignore`, then avatars won't be created *(because of lack of `img` directory)*. If I exclude the content of `img` directory, then all current user's avatars will be gone when I do a new git pull. Any idea how can I handle such a situation?

Comment: If you want the directory to exist but its contents to not be tracked, the convention is to put a `.gitkeep` file in `img/`, along with a `.gitignore` that excludes everything *except* the keep file. But that ignore file could be in a parent directory, see e.g. https://github.com/textbook/cyf-library/blob/master/server/.gitignore#L1 and https://github.com/textbook/cyf-library/tree/master/server/static where I've done a similar thing.

Comment: Git is not a deployment tool. It can be used as one, but it isn't *meant* to be one. A proper deployment tool would extract the commit to be deployed, *add any desired empty directories*, and then deploy that. Don't try to do this inside Git itself.

Answer (score 7):

Git doesn't track the directories, only the files.

In order to add an empty directory in the repo you have to put a file in it and write the correct rules in the project's `.gitignore`.

But, because a Git repository allows placing a `.gitignore` file in every directory you can put one in the directory you want to exclude and put these lines in it:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# ... but do not ignore this file
!.gitignore
```

Add the new file to the repository and commit it.

That's all.

---

If you want to keep all the ignoring rules in a single place (in the `.gitignore` file in the root directory of your project) then you can put an empty file in the directory to ignore and puts the rules above prefixed with the path into the `.gitignore` file.

Usually, such an empty file is named `.gitkeep` (the name doesn't matter, this one is used to express its purpose). In this case, add to the `.gitignore` file of the project:

```
/public/img/*
!/public/img/.gitkeep
```

---

If you have already added the files from `public/img` to the repository (and committed them) you have to remove them first in order to not be tracked any more. Run

```
git rm --cached public/img/*
```

and commit this change together with the changes in `.gitignore`. The `--cached` argument tells [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) to not remove the files from the working tree but only stop tracking them.

Comment: Thank you .. can you please take a look at my edited version?

Comment: I never do `git commit` on the server. Do I still need `git rm --cached` ?

Comment: You don't run this on the server but on your development machine. If you didn't add the files from `public/img` in the repo before then you can skip this part.

Answer (score 2):

You should see a `.gitignore` file in the working directory by issuing a `ls -la`. If not create a `.gitignore` file there(on the same level as the `.git` file).

In that file you can add the path to the `img` folder as such: `public/img/*`

Comment: Thank you .. can you please take a look at my edited version?

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't track directories, only files. What you can do is track any file in that directory, like a `.gitignore`, or even some file called `.placeholder`. You will also want to unversion the files in there but not remove the actual files, you can do this with `git rm --cached file`

```
# Untrack, but keep the existing files in img
git rm --cached myProject/public/img/*

# Create the placeholder file to keep the directory tracked
# You do not need this if any other versioned file exists
# in this directory or potentially any subfolders of this
# directory.
echo 'placeholder' > myProject/public/img/.placeholder

# Track the placeholder file in the img directory
git add myProject/public/img/.placeholder

# Commit your work
git commit -m 'YOUR COMMIT MESSAGE'
```